# Rally How can I export all the test cases that were run for a test set to CSV

Tags: rally

We want to take a number test cases from previous iterations / test sets and import them into a new test set. The problem is that we cannot export the test cases from a test set into CSV or any other data format as all we get is a printable report. We have also tried copy and paste the printable report into MS Excel but it does not give a data format.

Any suggestions / HTML forms that can be used.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to copy TestSets in Rally UI and that functionality allows re-using member Test Cases from Iteration to Iteration or from Release to Release. When you copy Test Sets they preserve the member Test Cases, including Test Steps.  Rally recommends this method to handle testing. If the same tests are use repeatedly, copy the test sets that contain them into the new iteration directly in the Rally UI.  This resets the results for that iteration and keeps you from duplicating the testcases.

Mark's Ruby tools provide an alternative which allows selective copying of member test cases - something that does not happen when a testset is copied in the UI.

Here is a javascript example using [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc3/doc/). You may certainly customize it further. The main point of this example is to illustrate how to update a collection using AppSDK2. 
A user may select a "source" iteration from the iteration combobox, then a testset combobox is populated with testsets scheduled for this iteration. Next a user can select a destination iteration from the third combobox that limits iterations to current and future iterations, and create a new testset scheduled for the "destination" iteration. The testcases from the "source" testset are copied to the new testset.

Currently updating collections will not work if the app is run outside of Rally, but this limitation will be corrected soon. It will allow collection updates outside of rally using CORS as long as `rab run` command is used. The code below should work inside Rally now. The deployment html is available from [this github repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/copy-testcases-from-one-set-to-another/tree/master/deploy).

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'iteration',
    comboboxConfig: {
        fieldLabel: 'Select a source Iteration',
        labelWidth: 150,
        width: 350
    },

    onScopeChange: function() {

        if (!this.down('#parentPanel')) {
            this._panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            layout: 'hbox',
            itemId: 'parentPanel',
            componentCls: 'panel',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'pickerContainer',
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    itemId: 'iterationContainer',
                }
            ]
        });
        this.add(this._panel);
        }

       if (this.down('#testSetComboxBox')) {
        this.down('#testSetComboxBox').destroy();   
    }

            var testSetComboxBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox',{
        itemId: 'testSetComboxBox',
        storeConfig: {
        model: 'TestSet',
        limit: Infinity,
        pageSize: 100,
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()]
        },
        fieldLabel: 'Select a TestSet',
        listeners:{
                ready: function(combobox){
            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
            this._onTestSetSelected(combobox.getRecord());
            }
            else{
            console.log('selected iteration has no testsets');
            }
        },
                select: function(combobox){

            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
                        this._onTestSetSelected(combobox.getRecord());
            }           
                },
                scope: this
            }
    });
    this.down('#pickerContainer').add(testSetComboxBox);   
    },
     _onTestSetSelected:function(testset){
        var id = testset.get('ObjectID');
        this._name = testset.get('Name');
        testset.self.load(id, {
            fetch: ['Name','TestCases'],
            callback: this._onSourceRecordRead,
            scope: this
        });
     },
      _onSourceRecordRead: function(record) {
        var that = this;
        that._testcases = [];
        var testcaseStore = record.getCollection('TestCases',{fetch:['Name','FormattedID']});
        testcaseStore.load({
            callback: function() {
                _.each(testcaseStore.getRange(), function(tc){
                    that._testcases.push(tc.data._ref);
                });
                console.log(that._testcases);
                that._selectFutureIteration();
            }
        });
    },

    _selectFutureIteration: function(){
        if (!this.down('#iterationComboxBox')) {
             var iterationComboxBox = Ext.create('Rally.ui.combobox.ComboBox',{
        itemId: 'iterationComboxBox',
        storeConfig: {
        model: 'Iteration',
        limit: Infinity,
        pageSize: 100,
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: [
                    {
                        property: 'StartDate',
                        operator: '>=',
                        value: (new Date()).toISOString()

                    }
                ]
        },
        fieldLabel: 'Select a destination Iteration',
            labelWidth: 150,
        listeners:{
                ready: function(combobox){
            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
            this._onFutureIterationSelected(combobox.getRecord());
            }
            else{
            console.log('no current or future iterations');
            }
        },
                select: function(combobox){

            if (combobox.getRecord()) {
                        this._onFutureIterationSelected(combobox.getRecord());
            }           
                },
                scope: this
            }
    });
    this.down('#iterationContainer').add(iterationComboxBox); 
        }

    },

    _onFutureIterationSelected:function(iteration){
        var that = this;
        that._iteration = iteration.data._ref;
        if (!this.down('#create')) { 
            var createButton = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype  : 'rallybutton',
                    text      : 'create a testset',
                    itemId: 'create',
                    handler: function() {
                        that._createTestSet(); 
                    }
                }

                ]
            });
        this.add(createButton);
        }

    },
    _createTestSet: function(){
        var that = this;
        console.log('create testset scheduled for ', that._iteration);
        Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'TestSet',
            success: function(model) { 
                that._model = model;
                var ts = Ext.create(model, {
                    Name: that._name + 'Copy',
                    Iteration: that._iteration
                });
                ts.save({
                    callback: function(result, operation) {
                        if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                            console.log(result.get('Name'), ' ', result.get('Iteration')._refObjectName);
                            that._readRecord(result);
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log("?");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    },

     _readRecord: function(result) {
        var id = result.get('ObjectID');
        this._model.load(id, {
            fetch: ['Name','TestCases'],
            callback: this._onRecordRead(result),
            scope: this
        });
    },

    _onRecordRead: function(record, operation) {
        console.log('There are ', record.get('TestCases').Count, ' in ', record.get('Name') );
        var that = this;
        var testcaseStore = record.getCollection('TestCases');
        testcaseStore.load({
            callback: function() {
                testcaseStore.add(that._testcases);
                testcaseStore.sync({
                    callback: function() {
                        console.log('success');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I did not know the test set copy functionality existed

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of Ruby scripts that might help you here:

- https://github.com/markwilliams970/Rally-Test-Set-Export
- https://github.com/markwilliams970/Rally-Add-TestCases-TestSet

These do require a working Ruby scripting environment and some familiarity with configuring/running scripts at the command line. However, working in combination, these should be enough to accomplish your goal.